# SQL Server Service does not start

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Windows 8.1. I have successfully installed SQL Server Management Studio, but services can't be started in "Sql configuration Manager". I search on google about these errors,and try all possible solutions but I am not able to resolve my error. Here is my error when I open services.msc and try to start services then this error generate[image: error image]

I can't start my services my sql configuration manager.Here is error image when i start services from configuration manager [image]

When I check parameters path then I can't find `MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf` in `C:\program File\Microsoft SQL Server` folder. Microsoft SQLfolder only contains two folders: 90 and 100.

Comment: Can you locate [errorlog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) file open it in notepad and add the output in question. Or you can go to event viewer and see the application logs as to why SQL Server is not starting

Comment: Search your drives for `master.mdf` and see if it exist.

Comment: What version of SQL Server Express are you using? 2012, 2014, 2016? Could you [add](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/124561/edit) the versions specific tag to your question?

Answer (score 4):

you need to find the corresponding error in event viewer in windows log\application find the error, one that the source is MSSQLServer and has happened, at the time you started the service.
detail of this error will help you resolve the issue.
(in the image below there is no error in it, it's just an information message, but in your case you may notice an error)
[image]

you may also want to check in system logs in event viewer, in the service Control manager to find a related error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you try starting the server services through command prompt?
if not, From a command prompt, enter the following command sqlservr.exe -s  and replace  with the name of the instance you want to start.

I hope this will  help.